# Understanding eigendecomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

By using eigendecompositon we can get a matrix similar to the original transformation matrix. That matrix is special since the diagonal contains all the eigenvalues.

The process that I use to obtain it is the following:

Consider T the transformation and $m(T)_{EE}$ the transformation matrix from the base E to the base E.

Calculate all the eigenvalues and their respective eigenvectors. Take the base of the subspace generated by all their eigenvectors and call it U.

Finally calculate $m(T)_{UU}$  which is $U^{-1}m(T)_{EE}U$.

The matrix that I get is a diagonal matrix which the diagonal contains all the the eigenvectors.

Having this explained what I've a problem understanding is *how* the final matrix is a diagonal matrix with all the eigenvalues. Calculating diagonal matrices is easy to me when the the "start" base is different than the "end" base (e.g $m(T)_{XY}$, I define the base X equal to the transformation and Y as the canonical so the end matrix is the identity). But in this case where they're equal I'm not really getting how it works.

Comment: I am quite confused by your question, isn't the transformation matrix from basis E to basis E just the identity (or I suppose some form of a permutation matrix if you allow shuffling the basis elements)?

Comment: The columns of the matrix are the coordinates of the images of the base vectors in the same base. If the image of every base vector is a multiple of itself, the matrix is diagonal.

Comment: @E-A. $m(T)_{EE}$ isn't the transformation matrix of one basis relative another; if so, it would have been the identity matrix. Instead, $m(T)_{EE}$ is the transformation matrix of the operator/transformation $T$ where both the domain and target spaces are the same and have the same basis $E$.

Comment: @md2 OK, yeah, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v_1$ be the first column of the matrix $U$. Then $v_1$ is an eigenvector of $T$; let $\lambda_1$ be the corresponding eigenvector. Therefore, $m(T)_{EE}.v_1=\lambda_1v_1$. In other words, if $e_1$ is the first vector of $E$, $m(T)_{EE}U.e_1=\lambda_1v_1$ and so$$U^{-1}m(T)_{EE}U.e_1=\lambda_1U^{-1}.v_1=\lambda_1e_1.$$This is true for all other vectors of $E$; in other words$$(\forall k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}):U^{-1}m(T)_{EE}U.e_1=\lambda_ke_k$$for some eigenvalues $\lambda_k$.

Comment: $U$ is $n\times m$ matrix, where the $n$ is dimension of the vector space(for example $R^n$). Then you cannot multiply $U$ by $e_1$. Is it true?

Comment: @GhD You're wrong. The matrix $U$ is a square matrix.

Comment: Eigenvectors of a matrix generate the whole space?!

Comment: @GhD In general, no.

Comment: So here $U$ is the base of subspace generated by eigenvectors. How it can be square?

Comment: @GhD Because in this case we are *assuming* that the matrix is diagonalizable. Note that the OP wrote “By using eigendecompositon we can get a matrix similar to the original transformation matrix.”